# Executing queries against PowerBI / SSAS using the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular library in Python?

Tags: python, powerbi, ssas

Is it possible to execute queries against PowerBI / SSAS servers using the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular library in Python?

I'm trying to "Select *" for a specific table in the DB and then store that as a CSV.

I've connected to the server which I've got as an object of the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server class. I can see in the documentation that there is an execute method for this class, but in my testing I haven't been able to make it work.